# i want to set path for downloaded PDF. where and how to set that?

Tags: pdf, download, path

in my controller page i had written this code for convert blade file into PDF and download it

```
 public function pdfview(Request $request)
 {
    $idd=$_GET['id'];
         $fees = \DB::table("feesdetail")->where('stu_id',$idd)->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview',compact('fees'));

        return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
  }
```

Comment: The server does not decide on the path where a file is saved on a client system.

Comment: so to perform that task any alternative way!???